# Eureka Bean Springboot 3

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

My server eureka is up.
but My application can't work because i have an error `*Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'*`

Hi,
My environment is

Java 17 and Springboot 3.2.1

i launch my eureka server on the port 9102.
But when i launch my application i get an error message

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.getApplications()" because the return value of "org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient()" is null
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:54) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:284) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

my config is :

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:9102/eureka/

Can you help me?

Comment: I don't get it... You said your eureka server is up, but then said that you got an error from eureka server. Does the error come from the eureka server or an eureka client? Is the eureka server running without a problem? 

I'm trying to understand the issue to be able to help you :)